# MySQL Stored Procedure Declare Issue

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

This problem has cost me almost an hour now and I know it is something simple.

I am getting the following error:

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'IN VARCHAR(256), hl7PatientId IN VARCHAR(256))
BEGIN

DECLARE mainQueue INT' at line 1
```

Here is my query which looks right to me:

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS insert_data;

CREATE PROCEDURE `insert_data`(hl7PatientName IN VARCHAR(256), hl7PatientId IN VARCHAR(256))
BEGIN

DECLARE mainQueue INT DEFAULT 1;

SELECT `queueid` INTO mainQueue FROM `queues` WHERE `description` LIKE 'Main' AND `enabled` = 1 LIMIT 1;

INSERT INTO `queue_data`
(`queueid`, `patientname`, `patientid`, `location`, `creationtime`, `priority`)
VALUES
(mainQueue, hl7PatientName, hl7PatientId, 'QUEUE_NUMBER', TIMESTAMP(), '');

END;
```

I am using MySQL 5.0.77 for this.

Can anybody see anything in this that is wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i've tidied up your example a little - note the use of delimiter and in params !

```
drop procedure if exists insert_queue_data;

delimiter #

create procedure insert_queue_data
(
in p_patientname varchar(255), -- size ? i always prefix my params p_ and keep the same name as the db field
in p_patientid varchar(255) -- size ? are you sure this isnt an integer ?
)
begin

-- i always prefix my variables v_ and keep same name as the db field

declare v_queueid int unsigned default 1;

select queueid into v_queueid from queues where
 description like 'Main' and enabled = 1 limit 1;

insert into queue_data(queueid, patientname, patientid, location, creationtime, priority) values
 (v_queueid, p_patientname, p_patientid, 'QUEUE_NUMBER', now(), '');

end#

delimiter ;
```

Comment: I noticed my IN being in the wrong spot and then I tried to do the delimeter but could not get it to work, but yours works perfect. So I am not sure what I was doing wrong.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Reverse the order of IN and parameter name.

```
...(IN hl7PatientName VARCHAR(256), IN hl7PatientId VARCHAR(256))...
```

Comment: That was one of the issues. Thanks.